# Rails `button_to` CSS Styling not working

Tags: css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, button

been trying to style my `button_to` button, however with no luck.
I've had a look in the CSS file and used 
`#button {color:red;}`, `button {color:red;}` and `.button {color:red;}` but to no avail for all of them. 
I also have this in my HTML.ERB file `<%= button_to 'Compare DB',:action => "compare", :id => 'button'` but that doesn't help.

Is there any reason why that doesn't work?

The CSS stylesheet is linked to the Rails app, as I tried changing the value for the table so that's not the issue.
Been trying for a while now, still can't figure out the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use style inline

```
<%= button_to 'Compare DB',:action => "compare", :id => 'button', {:style => "background: color:red; } %>
```

or you can use css clas like

```
<%= button_to 'Compare DB',:action => "compare", :id => 'button', {:class => "button"} %>
```

Comment: Nope that still doesn't work. I noticed my previous code works if there is no `:action=>"compare"`. Very strange, I need to be able to change it as well though

Comment: Ok figured out the problem, I should have done like what you told me to do
`<%= button_to 'Compare DB',:action => "compare", :id => 'button', {:style => "background: color:red; } %>`, paying close attention to the Brackets before `style`.
Thanks